# CSS : Displaying all li item of a list with hover

Tags: css, list, hover

I have a ul list (with 3 li items) where only the first item is displayed.

My code is very simple and is the following :

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
}

/*Hidding all the li item :*/
ul li {
  display: none;
}

/*But display only the 1st li item :*/
ul li.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="visible">Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to display all li items when my mouse cursor is on the 1st item.

Have you a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:hover`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) pseudo-class:

```css
ul:hover > li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

/* Hide all the list items */
ul > li {
  display: none;
}

/* But display the .visible ones, and
   all list items when list is hovered */
ul > li.visible, ul:hover > li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="visible">Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when all li items are displayed, i want the all li item remain displayed when my cursor pointer is on any li item, just like a menu.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. But it's not possible with css 2 (without the > character) ?

Comment: @totoaussi If you don't use `>`, it will match all `li` descendants, not only the children. You might want that, but in case of doubt I prefer `>`.